# Intuition eigenvectors graph Laplacian for weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Is there some interpretation for the eigenvectors of the Laplacian of a (directed) weighted graph? Normally, the spectrum of a Laplacian informs us about connectives, is this also the case for a weighted graph?

Comment: If you interpret the Laplacian in terms of random walks, that interpretation continues to function identically when the graph becomes weighted.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Would you use a weighted degree so that somehow to Laplacian becomes normalized so you get probabilities?

Comment: In the case of discrete random walks, a random walk on a weighted graph is just going to choose an edge to take with a probability proportional to its weight. Then you need to normalize. There's also continuous random walks, where the weight indicates the rate of an exponential random variable and no normalization is necessary. (There's like ten different ways to normalize a Laplacian, and especially in the case of directed graphs, I'm not sure what the "right" one is for these interpretations.)